# How to add EditText to ActionBar for ListView filtering?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an activity with action bar and one icon on this ActionBar. When user press this icon I need to hide this icon and show EditText with cross to clear text. When user will done with it (choose item in ListView or press back button) I will need to show icon again.

Here is two related question:
1. How to add EditText on ActionBar for ListView filtering?
2. How to change ActionBar between EditText and icon?

Before click:

[image]

After click on 'plus' icon:

[image]

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422072/searchview-in-listview-having-a-custom-adapter/23422665#23422665

Comment: @HareshChhelana, thank you! But this is not for ActionBar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a SearchView widget to your application.
The official documentation is here:
http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html

There are also detailed instructions to add it.

Comment: When I add `android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"` to my menu item, it changes icon from 'plus' to search icon with 'loupe'. It is not desired for me, I need a 'plus' icon.

Comment: You cannot change the default icon easily. Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445760/how-to-change-the-default-icon-on-the-searchview-to-be-use-in-the-action-bar-on

Answer (score 1):

**searchmenu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >      
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:title="search"
      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
      android:showAsAction="always"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

**mainactivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {     
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searchmenu, menu);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    setupSearchView();
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

     private void setupSearchView() {
            mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
            mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
            mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
        }

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        //implement the filterng techniques
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

    return false;
}
```

Comment: When I add android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" to my menu item, it changes icon from 'plus' to search icon with 'loupe'. It is not desired for me, I need a 'plus' icon.

Comment: use android:icon="@drawable/plus" in your searchmenu.xml

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How to add EditText on ActionBar for ListView filtering?

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11638739/2319390) by Commonsware . More clearly his [sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/ActionBarDemo) will do the trick.

> 2. How to change ActionBar between EditText and icon?

Simply override `onOptionItemSelected` and try to set the visibility of that menu item.

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.my_item);
item.setVisible(false);
```

Alternatively , If you want full control in your hands try to [customize your action bar](http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android)